# Python how to check os.exists if in same folder?

Tags: python, path

I have a program which saves and loads data which it stores in a text file. The file and the program are in the same folder. In order to save the file, the program must have been run at least once. To check if the save file has been created I wrote: (Some of it)

```
import os.path
def load_f():        
    global save_list
    if os.path.exists('Something.txt'):
        inFile = open('Something.txt', 'rb')
        save_list = inFile.read()
        inFile.close()
```

It can't seem to load the file. Is the path I wrote invalid. Do I need to add the folder name to the path?

Comment: Are you running this script in the folder containing `Something.txt`?

Comment: There is nothing obvious about this by reading your question.

Comment: @badzil I'll bet you a quid he put the file in the program directory, but ran the program from a different directory. You may need to define the terms of "obvious" :)

Comment: Can you make it clearer what is going wrong? Do you enter the loop? Can you open the file? Is `save_list` empty?

Comment: "The file and the program are in the same folder." Please read before commenting.

Comment: @madprogrammer: You can still run it from a different directory. I've asked about execution, not location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A file name without a path will be opened in the current working directory.

This is the same as `os.getcwd() + "/" + filename`

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo--should be `if os.path.exists('Something.txt'):`. Although I'd recommend choosing a different name anyway... :P

Also, I'd recommend changing the body of the `if` to:

```
with open('Something.txt', 'rb') as in_file:
  save_list = in_file.read()
```

This provides a safer (and shorter) way of making sure the file gets closed.

Comment: Thanks for shortening my code :D

Answer (score -2):

The Python idiom is that "it's easier to ask for forgiveness than for permission".

```
try:
    with open( "Something.txt", "rb" ) as f:
        print "Something.txt contains", f.read()
except IOError:
    print "Something.txt doesn't exist! (or we couldn't open it)"
```

Comment: While a nice pythonic representation, this does nothing to help figure out why the code above didn't work.